# Cmake cannot find boost library

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, cmake

I'm on Mac OS X, with the following CMake file, and Boost v1.58.0 installed at /usr/local/lib/boost_1_58_0, and every time I run cmake it prints "Could NOT find Boost". I've read through every stack overflow post I can about how to get this working, and nothing has worked. Is there something I'm just missing?

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.1)
project (HelloWorld)

set (CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "--std=gnu++11 ${CMAKE_C_FLAGS}")
file (GLOB SOURCE_FILES "source/*.cpp")

set (CMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH ${CMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH} /usr/local/lib/boost_1_58_0/boost)
set (CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH ${CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH} /usr/local/lib/boost_1_58_0/stage/lib)

set (Boost_NO_BOOST_CMAKE ON)   
set (BOOST_NO_SYSTEM_PATHS ON)
set (BOOST_ROOT /usr/local/lib/boost_1_58_0)
set (BOOST_INCLUDEDIR /usr/local/lib/boost_1_58_0/boost)
set (BOOST_LIBRARYDIR /usr/local/lib/boost_1_58_0/stage/lib)

set (Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS OFF)
set (Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED ON)
set (Boost_USE_STATIC_RUNTIME OFF)
find_package (Boost 1.58.0 COMPONENTS optional)

if (Boost_FOUND)
    include_directories (${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
    target_link_libraries (helloworld ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
endif ()

include_directories ("source")
add_executable (helloworld ${SOURCE_FILES})
```

Comment: Figured it out. optional isn't actually a library, because it's header-only.

Comment: Stylistic and portability point: you shouldn't be defining any system-specific stuff like BOOST_ROOT, BOOST_INCLUDEDIR and BOOST_LIBRARYDIR in your CMakeLists.txt.  If you do need to set these, do it on the command-line with -D.  The entire first boost stanza could be omitted, likewise for the include and library path set commands--use

    include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})

alone.

Comment: Additional portability comment: You use --std=gnu++11 but CMake offers compile features to put any supported compiler into the appropriate mode.  Also, don't append the *C* flags to the *CXX* flags.  Also, target_link_libraries should really come *after* add_executable since the target doesn't exist at this point.

Comment: Final note regarding Boost on MacOS X: have you tried homebrew?  I use this to provide Boost and a number of other libraries for development.  It works out of the box with no special settings required.  Might we worth a look if it makes your life easier.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. This is my first time using cmake really, and it feels like I'm getting teeth pulled.

Answer (score 3):

This was breaking because optional isn't a library, it's header-only, so changing it to `find_package (Boost 1.58.0)` fixed the problem.